# Microsoft Graph service fail with ms account

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

In my company, I need to upload Excel files on OneDrive.

We have a 365 Business Plan and every employee has an own 365 account, but I want to maintain just one repository for merged files and avoid to share the same repos account among all, so I prefer to implement a "***access without user***" through client credentials flow.

The first problem that I've met is the authorization: when I try to authorize the app by `/adminconsent` endpoint, it fails because my client account is not an administrator :-( 
 So I've tried to use another account, a simple Microsoft Account (for that I've made a new registration of the app in the Application Portal) but when I try to authorize the app I receive this error:

> "AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this API version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this."

What's wrong?

As an alternative, I've thought to continue with 365 Business employee accounts, create a folder with a tech account and share it, but when using Graph Explorer with an employee account and make the request

```
/me/drive/sharedWithMe
```

I receive just the shared folder but without the content

---

Here the code (I'm using the `requests_oauthlib` Python module):

In the beginning, I initialize the class object

```
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=config.CLIENT_ID)

self.oauth = OAuth2Session(
    client.client_id,
    scope=config.SCOPES,
    redirect_uri='https://me.local/allowed')
```

then I make a request for `authorization_url`

```
auth_base = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent' 
self.authorization_url, state = self.oauth.authorization_url(
    auth_base,
    state="12345")
return self.authorization_url
```

and the request for the token

```
return self.oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    client_id=config.CLIENT_ID,
    scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    client_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorization_response='https://me.local/authorized'
)
```

Comment: You cannot use the `client_credentials` grant with personal accounts (MSA) or without Admin Consent from the tenant.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur , you've right initially i passed client_credentials parameter. Now i've removed but the error is the same. i receive the error after i log on with Microsoft Account, at the beginning of last block of code. Best regards

Comment: It isn't the param that is the problem, it's the grant itself is not supported by MSA. Neither is `/adminconsent`. Personal accounts and services (i.e. Outlook.com, OneDrive, etc.) can only be accessed by an authenticated user using Delegated permissions that do _not_ require Admin Consent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a tenant administrator in order to consent application only access (where you only use client id and secret). However, you can use alternative flows such as  [Resource Owner Credentials Grant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) and [On-Behalf-Of Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) which requires you to have the credentials of a user with relevant permissions.

You can also read about those flows in my post:
[Getting Access Token for Microsoft Graph Using OAuth REST API](http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/).

Regarding the message with "version 2.0" - it may be caused by a mixup between version 1 and version 2 of the Microsoft OAuth API. Version 1 is only meant for organization users (users which sit inside azure active directory) and version 2 support Microsoft accounts as well. You can read more about the difference between the two versions in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare). Make sure you use one of those versions for the entire process (creating the app, assigning and consenting permissions, and requesting an access token). Mixing between the two versions may not work.

Comment: Spesifically, if you need to authenticate MSA users, you need to use the v2 Endpoint and register your application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. The v2 Endpoint supports both MSA and AAD accounts whiles v1 only supports AAD accounts. In general, unless you have a spesific need (i.e. Conditional Access, non-v2 APIs like Dynamics),  you should use the v2 Endpoint. It's the more flexiable of the two and eventually will replace v1 across the board. .

Comment: Thanks @Eran. i'm trying with On-Behalf-Of method but i receive `TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'grant_type'` .
The user is authenticated usign Authorization Code Grant flow, and then i call the token endpoint
`self.oauth.post(config.AUTHORITY_URL + 'common' + config.TOKEN_ENDPOINT, grant_type='urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', client_id=config.CLIENT_ID, client_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET, assertion=self.oauth.access_token, scope=['User.read'], requested_token_use='on_behalf_of')`
What else have i mistake?

Comment: Thanks Eran. I have to make a step back, i've bought a Udemy course on OAuth2 and i've solved many doubts. Thanks you so much for the support.